# Are all separable differential equations linear of the first order? Can all of them be solved using the integrating factor method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One of the things that I am struggling with differential equations is generalizing the way one should go about solving them. On that note,two questions circle through my mind:

- Are all separable differential equations linear of the first order?
- Can all (linear, first order) separable equations be solved using the integrating factor method?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678445/are-all-first-order-linear-differential-equations-separable) post partially answered these questions, but not entirely (I think).

Comment: There are  separable DE that  are not linear DE.

Comment: All $\bf{linear}$ ODEs of first order can be solved by integrating factor method (if there is a classical solution).

Comment: $\dfrac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=1$ is a separable DE (I’m not completely sure we can call it that, can someone verify this?) but not of first order.